# Remove Kubernetes Readiness Probe

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

My deployment had a readinessProbe configured like:

```
 readinessProbe:
    port: 8080
    path: /ready
    initialDelaySeconds: 30
    failureThreshold: 60
    periodSeconds: 10
    timeoutSeconds: 15
```

I want to remove the probe for some reason. However, after removing it from my YML file my deployment is not successful because look like the pod is never considered ready. Checking in GCP I discover that the result YML file has a readiness probe that points to some "default values" that I haven't set nowhere:

```
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /ready
        port: 80
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
```

Is there a way to actually remove a ReadinessProbe for good?

Comment: `I want to remove the probe as it's no longer necessary` IMHO, this is probably not true. If it is a webserver (as it looks like) you need to ensure at least it is listening to the configured port.

Comment: Ok, in this case, we have a livenessProbe :) But yep, I can remove the assertion to avoid branching the topic

Comment: Maybe you have some YML merging mechanism in between, either Kubernetes Helm or some other tool?

Comment: Besides that, have you tried to nullify it? `readinessProbe: null`

Comment: Another option is that you applied the YML **patching** instead of doing a full replacement.

Comment: Can you please provides us the helm chart you are using and the commands you are using to deploy/patch it?

Answer (score 8):

You need to set readinessProbe to null value like that:

```
readinessProbe: null
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem when trying to remove a `readinessProbe`. The only way I have found to successfully  do this is by first deleting the deployment then applying the deployment yaml to the cluster. This does cause some downtime but removes the probe for good.

```
`kubectl delete deployment <deployment-name>`
`kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`
```

Answer (score -2):

One possible way to remove the probe would be to modify changes to the configuration file(yaml file) and disable the Readiness Probe.

You can do this, by adding **enabled: false** to the configuration file. For example,

```
readinessProbe:
   enabled: false
   path: /ready 
   initialDelaySeconds: 30 
   failureThreshold: 60 
   periodSeconds: 10 
   timeoutSeconds: 15
```

If you are unable to modify the configuration file then, as mentioned by @G. Rafael try re-creating the deployment and apply the deployment configuration file to the cluster.

Comment: I get Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].livenessProbe): unknown field "enabled" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Probe, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].readinessProbe): unknown field "enabled" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Probe]

Comment: @Ironori try re-creating the deployment and apply the deployment configuration file to the cluster.

Comment: The field enabled is not accepted.

Comment: This is a setting you would usually set on a helm chart, which removes the `readinessProbe` spec